# MySQLSyntaxErrorException при выполнении запроса INSERT

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Суть проблемы:
Нужно вставить новую строку в таблицу hostel_project.orders (MySQL). Работаю через JDBC.

```
public class OrderDAOImpl implements OrderDAO {

    private static final String ORDER_ID = "orders.idorder";
    private static final String ORDER_PLACE_ID = "order.place_id";
    private static final String ORDER_USER_ID = "order.user_id";
    private static final String ORDER_PRICE = "order.price";
    private static final String ORDER_STATUS = "order.status";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL_ORDERS = "SELECT * FROM hostel_project.orders";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ORDER = "INSERT INTO hostel_project.orders(idorder,place_id,user_id,price,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    private static OrderDAOImpl instance = new OrderDAOImpl();

    public static OrderDAOImpl getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }



        public boolean createOrder(Order order) {
        DBConnectionPool pool = DBConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            connection = pool.takeConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_CREATE_ORDER);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1,order.getId());
            preparedStatement.setInt(2,order.getPlaceID());
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,order.getUsersID());
            preparedStatement.setFloat(4,order.getPrice());
            preparedStatement.setString(5,order.getStatus().toString());
            if (preparedStatement.executeUpdate() >0)//вот здесь выскакивает ошибка
                result = true;
        } catch (ConnectionPoolException|SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null)
                    preparedStatement.close();
                pool.closeConnection(connection);
            } catch (SQLException|ConnectionPoolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Ошибка такая:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hostel_project.user' doesn't exist
```

Я не могу понять, откуда эта таблица взялась.

Comment: проверьте существует ли пользователь `hostel_project.user`

Comment: В тексте метода order.getUsersID() что у Вас?

Comment: public int getUsersID() {
        return usersID;
    }